# Оставить только дубли в таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется таблица вида:

```
a|b|c
```

Как оставить только те строки, где значение "a" встречается больше одного раза?

**UPD:** a|b|c - это три столбца, столбцы b и с всегда уникальны и имеют разные значения, а значение столбца "а" может встречаться несколько раз

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пусть таблица называется `tbl`, и содержит три столбца `a`, `b` и `c`. Тогда для решения задачи можно поступить следующим образом

```
DELETE
  tbl
FROM
  tbl
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      a,
      b,
      c
    FROM
      tbl
    GROUP BY
      a
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) <= 1
  ) AS t
ON
  tbl.a = t.a AND
  tbl.b = t.b AND
  tbl.c = t.c
```

Comment: я так думаю, что *значение "a" встречается больше одного раза* - это a|a|b... Но это вопрос к  автору

Comment: Извиняюсь, если не особо точно выразился) a|b|c - это три столбца, столбцы b и c имеют всегда разные значения, а вот значение столбца "а" может встречаться несколько раз, т.е. сгруппировать не получится как я понимаю

Comment: @ВладиславГоловлёв, получится. Поправил ответ.